# Gunicorn timeout error, i cant increment it

Tags: flask, timeout, gunicorn

I have a flask app deployed on Digital Ocean,and the log error when i do a large request is:

`[1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:48)`

I tried to increment the timeout on Gunicorn this ways but the error persists:

#gunicorn_config.py

```
bind = "0.0.0.0:5000"
workers = 2
timeout = 600
```

#Procfile

`web: gunicorn app:app --timeout 600`

#env/Lib/site-packages/gunicorn/coonfig.py

```
class Timeout(Setting):
    name = "timeout"
    section = "Worker Processes"
    cli = ["-t", "--timeout"]
    meta = "INT"
    validator = validate_pos_int
    type = int
    default = 600
    desc = """\
```

Any idea what im doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Joa0. As you already know, gunicorn will bind to your flask app which is running on localhost:8080 as you wrote above, but make sure your app is actually running.

Comment: I will recommend you to follow this digitalOcean tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Thanks ged! i followed the digital ocean Flask one,but i will try/learn that one now!

Comment: I just want to be sure that the problem is not with your application, let's check. On your server, **activate your virtual env** and try to start your application's manual by typing something like this


 ```python main.py```

Let's see if it works correctly.

NB: main.py or app.py reagarding to your app

Comment: It is working good that way,can test it on my deploy url too:
http://jjtrading-yzukr.ondigitalocean.app/api/minsmax?days_back=3d&coins_quantity=2 doesnt takes much time and goes good,but when i start requesting more coins (more time),i get the [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:48) on digital ocean and 504 error on the browser console when i request from the front

Answer (score 1):

try to point to your configuration file

```
gunicorn -c gunicorn_config.py --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:app
```

note that for this statement to work you need wsgi.py also in the same directory having the following

```
from myproject import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Cheers!